# how to replace include path in a C file with sed?

Tags: sed, regular-expression

Say I have

```
#include <prog1/foo.h>
#include <prog1/bar.h>
#include <prog1/baz.h>
```

I have to replace it with

```
#include <prog1/prog1/foo.h>
#include <prog1/prog1/bar.h>
#include <prog1/prog1/baz.h>
```

I only know how to find the original match, like:

```
sed -i -e '/#include\s<prog1\/.*\.h>/' testfile
```

But have no clue how to put something in the middle of string

Comment: why not just say `-I prog1` when compiling ? the compile then the look in `prog1/` for `<>` includes  and find further subdirectory `prog1` containing  foo.h` there.

Answer (score 3):

**`sed`** approach:

```
sed -E '/^#include/ s/<prog1/&\/prog1/' testfile
```

The output:

```
#include <prog1/prog1/foo.h>
#include <prog1/prog1/bar.h>
#include <prog1/prog1/baz.h>
```

---

- `-E` option is added for more extended cases. The current simple one will work even without it.

Comment: sed does not have a -E option. Did you like to write -e instead?

Comment: @schily, I recommend you to read `sed` manual. Here's some citation:  `Use the POSIX-specified -E option (-r, --regexp-extended) to enable Extended Regular Expression (ERE) syntax` and another cite `but the -E extension has since been added to the POSIX standard (http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=528), so use -E for portability.`

Comment: I recommend you to make a related bug report since the most recent standard does not include -E, see: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html

Comment: @schily, I recommend you to somehow prove that this approach won't work on all Linux systems ... and update the documentation

Comment: This is a UNIX group and the OP did not mention to run Linux.

Comment: @Roman for some reason that issue is tagged “issue8”, so presumably it won’t be included until the next release (even though it was accepted long before issue 7 was published).

Comment: @schily, If you read dwheeler's enhancement request, the one linked above, you'll see he notes that `-E` is already supported very widely. Even busybox's sed supports it.

Comment: This does not help as it is not supported on any certified POSIX platform except for MacOS

Comment: @Stephen Kitt: thank you for mentioning this tag! This means that it will take at least two years before there will be a related standard that includes the enhancement. The URL I quoted is for the latest version of the standard that refreshed it as IEEE standard for the next 10 years. So the correct text would be that the `-E` option will be added to the standard in the future and we expect certified systems where this feature was included in the certification tests in aprox. 5 years.

Comment: @schily, if you think all answers should be usable on any certified POSIX platforms, or otherwise restricted to strictly standard features, I'd suggest you [take it up on meta](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). Right now, I see lots and lots of answers here that aren't strictly limited to POSIX features. Many of them note that, some don't.

Comment: I have no problems with answers that include non-standard behavior as long as they are flagged to be non-portable,